# ASP.NET Identity - Using Roles with JavaScript Functionality

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an application using JQuery DataTables.  I want these tables to display for every user, but only allow the click functionality for users in a specific role.

So, I can set up authorization on the controllers with this...

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

That's not enough because there will still be a call to this controller and method and a redirection for those not in the "Admin" role.

Let's say I have a function in my javascript like this...

```
//Click event on the table row
$('#table1').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    //Post the data to the controller
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        data: {someData : someData},
        success: function () {
            //do something 
        }
    });
});
```

I'd like to wrap something around this around the click event...

```
if (role == "Admin") { //click event in here }
```

Now, I know that the roles are on the server side, while the javascript is on the client side.
I've seen some suggestions about using razor syntax to output something into a hidden column and then grab that value with the javascript.  Something like this...

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="isAdmin" value="true">
}
```

But, that's not really secure, because the hidden fields can still be accessed.
What proper way can I use these identity roles to work with my javascript?

Comment: You need to avoid having the click event on the page at all for the users that shouldn't see it, otherwise there is nothing preventing them from manipulating the if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One relatively easy approach is to move your admin JavaScript to a separate file and only include it if the user is in your admin role. E.g.:

```
@Scripts.Render("bundles/js/app")

if (User.IsInRole("Admin") {
  Scripts.Render("bundles/js/admin")
}
```

That way, it can progressively enhance the app for admins by lighting up admin-specific features to augment the regular users' experience.

Obviously, the most important line of defense is still the `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller or action though. No Razor view tricks or JavaScript shenanigans can replace that.

Comment: This is one method I did think of.  Thanks.  I was going to ask if this was a good thought.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without passing a model

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("administrator"))

If it is a single page app you'll have to pass a model. If a hacker changes his role to admin in javascript they will see the click buttons but won't be able to do anything with it if they arnt an admin.